# Serialize Expression<Func<object>>

Tags: c#, serialization, expression, func

i have an issue if i serialize an expression.

I have the objects "Parent" and "Child".
"Child" is nested in "Parent".

Now i create:

```
Parent parent = null;
Expression<Func<object>> exp = () => parent.Child;
```

As far as is concerned.

But if i serialize the expression, it fails because "parent" is null and "parent.Child" is also null.

```
string serializeResult = SerialzeHelper.Serialize(exp);
```

I only need the serialized expression. Not an instance of "Parent" or "Child".

Is there an serializer (and deserializer) which can deal with it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Parent is null because you've set it to null. Try `Parent parent = new Parent()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I only need the expression and not the concrete instance. Is there an solution the Serializer only serialize the structure?

Comment: You want to serialize an expression pointing to your local variable? How would you expect that to work?

Comment: Booth, the local variable and the expression are serialized. The result should be processes as JoinAlias (deserialized at the point) in NHibernate. http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/03/16/queryover-series-part-2-basics/

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the point of an expression. Your expression basically says - when executed, please return the value of a `Child` property of an object which resides at this memory address. How would you expect this to be serialized and how this should behave after deserializing?

Comment: You need to serialize the functionality _(what the expression does)_ so you can rebuilt it on deserialization, it should not contain any references.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen van Langen: You mean that i should pass the logic (e.g. object-name and property-name) und build the expression just in time if needed?

Comment: Your expression should probably take a `Parent` as argument, instead of referring to a local variable.

Comment: @csharp_developer You should parse the expression tree and check the types of the expressions. _(you'll have to write the serializable classes yourself)_ You should serialize that. When deserializing, you should  check the expressions types and find the parameters. This is all runtime so you won't be able to call it directly as a function with parameters. It's tough stuff, so think twice. You'll probably better of implementing the expressions at both sides.

Comment: Thanks at all for the fast help. I will try the approach form Jeroen.